# Ember js handling API endpoints with nested resource URLs

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

A portion of my API is setup as follows:

`/v1/place/:place_uuid` - retrieve a place

`/v1/place/:place_uuid/cart` - retrieve a shopping cart object associated with that place

My routes are setup correctly (see below) but the API requests made by Ember don't match my own.

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('place', { path: '/:place_uuid' }, function() {
        this.resource('category', { path: '/:category_uuid' }, function() {
            this.resource('product', { path: '/:product_uuid' });
        });
        this.resource('cart', { path: '/cart' });
    });
});
```

When I load `/:place_uuid` in a browser I see an API request to `/v1/place/:place_uuid` which is correct. The route renders with the returned object.

When I load `/:place_uuid/cart` in a browser I see the same as above but also a 2nd API request to `/v1/carts`. This is all fine except for the `/v1/carts` URL. I need it to be `/v1/place/:place_uuid/cart`

I tried to use buildURL with a custom adapter for the Cart model.. but no luck. I don't have access to place_uuid anywhere below so I can't inject it in.

```
cartAdapter = App.Adapter.extend({
  buildURL: function(record, suffix) {
    console.log(record); // just a string. 
    var url = [this.url];
    url.push('places');
    url.push(place_uuid); // if only I had access to place_uuid I could inject it here
    url.push('cart');
    return url.join("/");
  }
});
App.Store.registerAdapter('App.Cart', cartAdapter);
```

It would be great if I could use my original API endpoint, I suppose another option would be to change the endpoint to `/v1/carts?place_uuid=:place_uuid` (which Ember seems to prefer, but is a bit tricky as I don't work on the backend).

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ember does not support nested REST URLS/resources yet.  There is an [open issue for this functionality](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/186) that you can monitor.

Comment: This seems to be an issue still. I'd love to ignore the world and pretend such APIs won't exist - but they do. So is my only solution to switch frameworks or are there recommended hacks to circumvent the behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach:

Patch your DS.Store like this:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default {
  name: 'patches',

  initialize: function() {
      // +++ Nested routes +
      DS.Store.reopen({
          __nestedAdapter__: null,

          nest: function(type) {
              this.set('__nestedType__', this.adapterFor(type));
              return this;
          },

          withResources: function(resources) {
              this.get('__nestedType__').set('nestedResources', resources);
              this.set('__nestedType__', null);
              return this;
          }
      });
  }
};
```

Add this to your adapter:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({

    nestedResources: {},

    buildURL: function(type, id, record) {
        var resources = this.nestedResources;
        var parts = [this.get('host')];

        for(var key in resources) {
            if (resources.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                var resource = resources[key];
                parts.push(
                    Ember.Inflector.inflector.pluralize(key)
                );
                if(isNaN(resource)) {
                    parts.push(resource.get('id'));
                } else {
                    parts.push(resource)
                }
            }
        }

        parts.push(
            Ember.Inflector.inflector.pluralize(type),
            id
        );

        this.set('nestedResources', {});
        console.log(parts.join('/'));
        return parts.join('/');
    }

});
```

Use an expressive syntax:

```
that.store.nest('user').withResources({comment: comment}).find('user')
```

This can be shortened for sure, but i like it like that.

Answer (score 1):

Shameless plug :)

I wrote https://github.com/amiel/ember-data-url-templates to help with just this kind of situation. It works with newer versions of ember-data. With it, you can do something like this:

```
App.CartAdapter = App.ApplicationAdapter.extend({
  queryUrlTemplate: "/v1/place/{placeId}/cart",

  urlSegments: {
    placeId(type, id, snapshot, query) {
      return query.placeId;
    }
  }
});


// in the route
this.store.query('cart', { placeId: placeId });
```

I hope that helps :)